# Handling Promises: How to return a list having promises from a for loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, amazon-cognito

I m trying to push all the returned promises from AWS-Cogntio into a list inside a for loop. I want to return the same list as the final result.

So basically, I m trying to upload a list of users to AWS-Cognito, and i want to return every user's response from Cognito, in a list.

This is the code I have:

```
let list = [];
body.forEach(async(userItem) => {
    await this.userService.uploadUser(userItem)   //uploading every user to AWS
    .then((user) => {               //'user' is the promise returned from AWS
         list.push(user);        
         console.log("list::::", list);                             
    });
})
```

This is what i tried to do: But the list contains only one value and not the list of values.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    body.forEach(async(userItem) => {
        await this.userService.uploadUser(userItem)   //uploading every userItem to AWS
        .then((user) => {               //'user' is the promise returned from AWS
             list.push(user);        
             console.log("list::::", list);                             
        });
    })
 }).then((data) => {
     return res.send(list);         //same list of promises
})
```

This is the output i get, when i m trying to upload for multiple users:

```
[
    {
        "message": "An account with the given email already exists.",
        "code": "UsernameExistsException",
        "time": "2019-05-06T07:15:28.113Z",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 57.99626693113027
    }
]
```

**EDIT :**
From the answers given below, this works: Using map instead of for loop returns the same length of list having promises.

```
try {
    let promises = body.map(async(userItem) => {
        let user = await this.userService.uploadUser(userItem);         
        return await new Promise((resolve) => {         
            resolve(user);      
        })      
    });     
    let data = await Promise.all(promises);     
    res.send(data);     
    } catch (error) {       
          throw error;  
    } 
}
```

This gives me result list of all the user responses. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even use `async`/`await` if you chain by `then` anyway and don't care about the result?

Comment: The reference of that question tells only how to get all the promises and resolve it using Promise.all. It doesn't answer my question. I request to keep the question open. 
.then() ,catch() is used as I need to handle the AWS success and errors returned from the AWS service block. 
Even If i remove .then(), I m trying to see how I can resolve those promises i get in the list. Tried with Promise.all() as suggested, and couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use `Promise.all`, please? And yes, getting all the promises and using `Promise.all` to wait for them to get the `list` of results seems to be precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `forEach` isn't `async/await` aware. So try instead with map to return the desired promise lists. 
Refer to this for more info on [async/await in loops](https://dev.to/zellwk/javascript-async-and-await-in-loops-2g43).

I don't know if I understood this correctly but this is what I would do:

```
   const list = body.map(async (userItem) => {
        await this.userService.uploadUser(userItem))
    });

   Promise.all(list).then(() => console.log('worked')).catch(() => console.log('it didnt work'));;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: Was following the logic the person asked. You can ofc instead of pushing to the list just `const list = body.map((userItem) => this.userService.uploadUser(userItem))`.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael, that was helpful. But how do i resolve the promises that i m pushing it in the list ?  If i don't  resolve those promises returned, i get the list as empty inside Promise.all function.

Comment: That's weird, can you console.log() the result of uploadUser per iteration?
It should be returning a Promise

Comment: Yes i tried, list i get in the loop has all the promises , and console.log() inside Promise.all has the result list empty, as its getting executed asynchronously.
I need to resolve those promises so that Promise.all might get the final list.

Comment: The `try`/`catch` makes no sense, unless you place an `await` on the promise.

Comment: Tried placing await. Its still getting executed asynchronously and returns null list.

Comment: `try/catch` blocks aren't only used in the context of `async/await` in that case it could even throw the error if Promise.all attempts to resolve a non-Promise. Thats what I was trying to catch right there.

Comment: Can you please retry with the above mentioned edited code? 
forEach isn't await aware so it won't work with async/await.

Comment: Yes you are right, forEach doesnt know to wait for promises.  Your edited code missing the resolve promise of every userItem? I have added the working code above, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Promise.all(body.map(userItem => this.userService.uploadUser(userItem))
  .then((list) => {
     res.send(list);
  })
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation to your code about how & why it works so that less experienced developers can fully understand it